# Why Sonata Admin doesn't save my custom doctrine field?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I writed the simpliest Money class ever:

```
class Money 
{
     private $amount;
     private $currency;

     // getters and setters here

     public function toArray() { 
          return ['amount' => $this->amount, 'currency' => $this->currency]; 
     }
}
```

Then I created Doctrine custom type which extend Sonata's JsonType:

```
class MoneyType extends JsonType
{
    /**
     * @param Money $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return mixed|null|string
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return parent::convertToDatabaseValue($value->toArray(), $platform);
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return new Money(parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'money';
    }
}
```

Then I added it in my config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
            money: Enl\CurrencyBundle\Doctrine\Type\MoneyType
```

Then I added form type for this data piece:

```
class MoneyType extends AbstractType
{
    // Some trivial getters and setters for dependencies here

    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'enl_money';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'currencies' => $this->getPossibleCurrencies(),
            'data_class' => 'Enl\CurrencyBundle\Model\Money'
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('currency', 'choice', ['choices' => $options['currencies'], 'required' => true])
            ->add('amount', 'number', ['required' => true]);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

And then I added the field to my model:

```
/**
 * @var Money
 * @ORM\Column(type="money", nullable=true)
 */
protected $price;
```

And finally my sonata admin form:

```
    $form
        ->with('editor.dish', ['class' => 'col-md-8'])
            ->add('price', 'enl_money')
    // blah-blah-blah
```

The problem is that Sonata Admin just doesn't save the form value!

I added var_dump($object); to Admin::update() method - the new value is there in object.
After that I created the simple test:

```
    $dish = new Dish();
    $dish->setPrice(new Money(7000, "BYR"));

    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $em->persist($dish);
    $em->flush();
```

It works! What should I change in my Admin class to get this working?

Comment: you have to follow the symfony documentation to create and use your custom type even with sonata .
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: I do follow this doc. I have custom Form type and custom Doctrine Type. Everything looks ok (form type is defined properly) and works on-read ok (doctrine fullfills form widget when I paste json into column via PhpMyAdmin). 

The problem is somewhere in Sonata configuration. Or maybe, that's a bug.